# how many different types of algebra are there? I mean Boolean, relational, predicate, fuzzy algebra, etc

Tags: algebra, relational-algebra

hi I am a computer science graduate student right now I am studying soft computing during this I face many terms like boolean relational predicate fuzzy 
so, one question arises in my mind how many different types of algebra are there

Comment: "Algebra" is a generic term used generally for collections of values & operators on them. What has your research shown? How is, say, the Wikipedia article not adequate? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Questions asking for lists of things are generally not on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it meets none of the [ask]/[help] "What topics can I ask about here?" [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) criteria, "a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: I agree with closing this question. I also downvoted Arun's (not a) answer; and added a comment explaining why; but that comment got deleted, it seems.

Answer (score -3):

I GOT THE ANSWER BUT ANYONE WANTS TO ADDON IT THEN I WILL BE HAPPY.
Fuzzy logic is a mathematical language to express something.
This means it has grammar, syntax, semantic like a language for
communication.
There are some other mathematical languages also known
• Relational algebra (operations on sets)
• Boolean algebra (operations on Boolean variables)
• Predicate logic (operations on well-formed formulae (WFF), also
called predicate propositions)
Fuzzy logic deals with Fuzzy set